# Route Slug Always Being Queried - Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

Here's my **web.php** file:

```
Route::get('/items', 'ItemsController@index');
Route::get('/items/create', 'ItemsController@create');
Route::get('/items/{item}', 'ItemsController@show');
Route::post('/items', 'ItemsController@store');
Route::delete('/items/{item}', 'ItemsController@destroy');

Route::get('/items/deleted', 'DeletedItemsController@index');
```

How do I prevent the **/items/deleted** slug from being considered a wildcard?

> **NotFoundHttpException** No query results for model [App\Item].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `/items/deleted` route definition above wildcard:

```php
Route::get('/items', 'ItemsController@index');
Route::get('/items/create', 'ItemsController@create');

Route::get('/items/deleted', 'DeletedItemsController@index');

Route::get('/items/{item}', 'ItemsController@show');
Route::post('/items', 'ItemsController@store');
Route::delete('/items/{item}', 'ItemsController@destroy');
```